# How can i close a GTK window after i've opened a new one?

Tags: c, user-interface, widget, window, gtk3

I'm trying to develop a simple menu on GTK, with C on VSCode and Linux Mint, the idea is to create a window and make each of the buttons open a new window and close the previous one, but i'm having a hard time with it.

You can see in the code below that only one of the buttons is actually programmed to open the submenu, but when it's open the previous window won't close and i have no idea of how to make it.

I'm new to programation so i'd be gratefull if you could expĺain it "for dummies".

> 

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void submenu (GtkWidget *window){
    gtk_window_close(window);
    GtkWidget *window2, *result2, *fixed2, *opt12, *opt22, *opt32, *opt42, *opt52;

    window2 = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window2), "Test");
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window2), 828, 512);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window2), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    g_signal_connect(window2, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    fixed2 = gtk_fixed_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window2), fixed2);

    result2 = gtk_label_new("Choose an option");
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed2), result2, 374, 100);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(result2, 80, 30);

    opt12 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Option 1");
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed2), opt12, 289, 180);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(opt12, 250, 30);

    opt22 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Option 2");
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed2), opt22, 289, 220);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(opt22, 250, 30);

    opt32 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Option 3");
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed2), opt32, 289, 260);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(opt32, 250, 30);

    opt42 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Option 4");
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed2), opt42, 289, 300);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(opt42, 250, 30);

    opt52 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Option 5");
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed2), opt52, 289, 340);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(opt52, 250, 30);
    
    gtk_widget_show_all(window2);
}

void menu (){
    GtkWidget *window, *result, *fixed, *opt1, *opt2, *opt3, *opt4, *opt5;

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Main menu");
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 828, 512);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    fixed = gtk_fixed_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), fixed);

    result = gtk_label_new("Escolha uma Option");
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), result, 374, 100);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(result, 80, 30);

    opt1 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Option 1");
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), opt1, 289, 180);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(opt1, 250, 30);
    g_signal_connect(opt1, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(submenu), NULL);

    opt2 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Option 2");
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), opt2, 289, 220);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(opt2, 250, 30);

    opt3 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Option 3");
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), opt3, 289, 260);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(opt3, 250, 30);

    opt4 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Option 4");
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), opt4, 289, 300);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(opt4, 250, 30);

    opt5 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Option 5");
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), opt5, 289, 340);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(opt5, 250, 30);
    
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    menu();

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

i'm compilling with

```
gcc intertest.c -o intertest `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used gtk before but maybe this will help you never the less.  When you click "Option 1" it opens the sub-menu but then both windows disappear.  This is because in menu you have this signal handler set:

```
g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
```

which cause the application to exit when the first window is closed.  It seems to work as expected when you comment it out.